# How can I access jQuery variable in controller and model (code igniter) in order to send data to database?

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

How can I access jQuery variable in controller and model (code igniter) in order to send data to database?

Script:

```
<script>
    var firstSeatLabel = 1;
    $(document).ready
    (
        function() 
     {
     var $cart = $('#selected-seats'),
     $counter = $('#counter'),
     $total = $('#total'),
     sc = $('#seat-map').seatCharts({
     map: [
```

Controller:

```
public function checkout()
{
    $selected_seats=$this->input->post('selected_seats');   
    $total=$this->input->post('total');
    $table='seat_details';
    $data=array('selected_seats'=> $selected_seats,'total_amount'=>$total);
```

View:

```
<h3> Selected Seats (
        <span id="counter"> 0</span>
        ):
    </h3>
     <ul id="selected-seats"></ul>Total: 
     <b>$ <span id="total">0</span> </b>
    <form action="<?php echo site_url('Welcome/checkout');?>" method="POST">
                <button class="checkout-button" type="submit">
                      Checkout
                 </button>
```

Comment: You need to remove the HTML from the controller.  The view should contain the HTML, the controller is then passing information to both the view and the model.  Pass the variables from the view by either seting the value on the form inputs or by using ajax.  Then pass those variable from teh view to the model and let the model process and insert as required.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery to set input value and use PHP to fetch the value in your script:

```
$('#input-checkout').attr('value',20);
```

Your page shoud have an hidden field like below:

```
<input type="hidden" name="checkout" id="input-checkout">
```

In your CI controller you just fetch the Checkout value like this:

```
$checkout= $this->input->post('checkout');
```

Comment: i dont hav <input> field in my code instead it is defined in script as follows             var $cart = $('#selected-seats'),
      $counter = $('#counter'),
      $total = $('#total'),
      sc = $('#seat-map').seatCharts({
      map: [
      'ffffff_ffffff',
      'ffffff_ffffff',
      'eeeeee_eeeeee',
      'eeeeee_eeeeee',
      'eeeeee___',
      'eeeeee_eeeeee',
      'eeeeee_eeeeee',
      'eeeeee_eeeeee',
      'eeeeee',
          ],
     seats: {